# Indices of dataframe columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The main problem is to create a list full of categorical factor's indices

There is dataframe with lots of columns types of which were detemined before importing file with `pd.read_csv()`.

```
dtypes = {
    ...
    'Format_type': 'category',
    'Geo_new': 'category',
    'Age_min': 'int16',
    'Age_max': 'int16',
    'Sex': 'category',
    ...}
```

So I made a table with **columns names and their indices**, and than take *categorical colums* by myself

```
col_list = [i for i in (df.columns.get_values())]
idx_list = [i for i in range(len(df.columns.get_values()))]
column_num = pd.DataFrame(data = {'column_name': col_list,
                                  'idx_list': idx_list})
column_num
```

Than get table of columns name `column_name` and indices `idx_list`

```
column_name idx_list
...
Format_type 5
Geo_new     6
Age_min     7
Age_max     8
Sex         9
...
```

and insert categorical columns indices in the list:

`categorical_features = [...5, 6, 9...]`

Thus, i fill list by myself. Is there the way to create list of columns, which values are `calegory` automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) with [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) for indices:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':pd.Categorical([4,5,4,5,5,4]),
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D': pd.Categorical([1,3,5,7,1,0]),
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

c = df.select_dtypes('category').columns
print (c)
Index(['B', 'D'], dtype='object')

i = df.columns.get_indexer(df.select_dtypes('category').columns)
print (i)
[1 3]
```

Also your code should be simlify:

```
col_list = df.columns.tolist()
idx_list = range(len(col_list))
column_num = pd.DataFrame(data = {'column_name': col_list, 'idx_list': idx_list})
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer!
```df.select_dtypes('category').columns``` return columns names with categorical types, but i need their indices

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to do it!

`categorical_list = list(np.where(df.dtypes == 'category')[0])`